# Calling methods that are not subject to the test?

Tags: unit-testing

I'm currently trying to figure out how to write proper unit tests. There still is a lot to learn. One scenario I would like to ask about is the following:

Suppose I am testing method `A` of class `X`. Now I often find it necessary to call a method `B` (of `X`) that is not subject of the current test. Most of the time, this happens to either set up the test fixture (i.e. changing the state of `X`) or asserting something about `A` (i.e. making an assertion about the state of `X`). In both cases, mocking is futile. However, if I make any (faulty) changes to `B`, then test `A` may fail even though nothing about `A` has changed.

Now, I am unsure about how to interpret this outcome. Does it mean that my testing process or design is flawed, or is it a non-issue since I am, after all, testing the unit "`X`" (the class)?

Comment: If you change code in `B` and the test for `A` fails it **still tells you that you broke stuff**. It also tells you which test fails. Since you know what you changed, it's not really important which test helps you identify it, unless you want to not run the full test suite every time while developing. I believe mocking only makes sense if you have external dependencies like a DB or a webservice.

Comment: The question is too abstract for me to have a strong opinion, but the bottom line for me is that if a test helps you find or prevent bugs in your code without being a maintenance nuisance, that's a good test.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the reason the test of `A` fails is because the object of class `X` is in an invalid state as a result of a problem with `B`, there is not necessarily any problem with your testing design. Really you should have some unit tests of `B` which fail before you even get to testing `A`. That way, you can assume that if those tests pass, any test failure of `A` is a result of a problem with `A`.

The typical way to write unit tests is to assume that every method not under test works properly. This is only useful, though, if those other methods have their own unit tests to catch bugs when they are introduced. If you don't have that, though, a failure of your test case for `A` that is caused because you recently introduced a bug into `B` could leave you barking up the wrong tree.

Comment: "The typical way to write unit tests is to assume that every method not under test works properly." - exactly the info that I was looking for. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @AndyBrandi don't ignore the next sentence, though! That's crucial!